# Python for loop in avoid similar match

Tags: python, for-loop, match

Consider the following list:

```
items = ['about-conference','conf']
```

Iterating over the list using the following for loop prints "about-conference" and "conf"

```
for word in items:
    if 'conf' in word:
        print word
```

How do I get the if statement to only prove true if it encounters an exact match i.e printing "conf" only?

Thank you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Don't use `in`, use `==` to test for exact equality:

```
if word == "conf":
   print word
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do the following :

```
for word in list:
    if 'conf' == word.strip():
        print(word)
```

Strip ensure that there is not spurious character such as blank space or end of line.

Answer (score 2):

Not exactly sure what you want but in case you are looking for something like this which uses word boundaries so it seperates by dashes, spaces, start of string etc.

```
import re
for word in items:
    if 'conf' in re.findall(r'\b\w+\b', word):
        print 'conf'
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
for word in list:
    if word == 'conf':
        print word
```

Answer (score 0):

In this specific example, you can rewrite that as:

```
items = ['about-conference','conf']
if 'conf' in items:
    print 'conf'
```